# TwoSum Algorithm (Python): Index of dupluicate elements treated as same

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I am trying to solve the twoSum LeetCode problem via a brute force algorithm. Essentially the question is to find the indexes of two numbers that equal to the target. So if I had a list [7,2,4,1] and my target was 9, I would return index of 7 & 9 (which in this ex is [0,1]) as the solution.

**I have written this algorithm here:**

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:

    if (len(nums) < 2):
        return False

    count = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range (i+1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                ans =  str(nums.index(nums[j])) + str(nums.index(nums[i]))
                return ans
            count = count + 1
```

It works for everything except the one scenario where two elements in a list are duplicates. So if the list contained [3,3] with target 6, my algorithm is returning index [0,0] instead of [0,1]. What is causing this issue and what would be the proper solution to fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ans =  str(nums.index(nums[j])) + str(nums.index(nums[i]))
```

This happens because you try to obtain the index of 3 on this line twice, which will return index 0 twice. Why not return string of `i` and `j` itself since they are already indices?
So:

```
ans =  str(j) + str(i)
```

Comment: I see! That solution works, time complexity is n^2 which leetCode doesn’t except but that’s fine. I am only learning brute force algorithms first in class right now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not from your algorithm but in the way you translate the answer in string (`ans =  str(nums.index(nums[j])) + str(nums.index(nums[i]))`)

`l.index(i)` will return the first index of `l` containing the value i,  so when the value is duplicated, `nums.index(nums[j])==nums.index(nums[i])`, I believe you actually want to have `ans =  str(j) + str(i)` instead